# Is there a way to change the type of a variable in relation to a string?

Tags: python, csv, types, opc-ua

I'm creating a program in python that reads a CSV file.
The CSV looks like that:

```
Var1,type1,val1
Var2,type2,val2
Var3,type3,val3
...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to change the type of the value depending on the type.
I can do it with a switch/case but there are many different types (The classical ones + SByte, DiagnosticInfo, DataTime, ...) and I am searching for a general solution.
I don't know if it matters but my application is on OPC UA (I think that's why there is so many different types).

Comment: Providing more detailed input and output example would help. What types do you have in your CSV file? What types should have the output?

Comment: You can use a dictionary that maps type names to the function for parsing the value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

To pickup on @Barmar's comment, you can use a dictionary where each key is a type (e.g., 'int', 'float') and its value is a function that can transform the string values from the CSV ('1', '2.9') into the real value (1, 2.9):

```py
import csv
import io
from datetime import date

csv_file = io.StringIO(
    """
Var1,int,1
Var2,date,2022-08-01
Var3,int,2
Var4,str,Toaster oven
Var5,float,3.14159
Var6,foo,����
""".strip()
)


def default_f(x: str) -> str:
    """Returns x as-is, a string; used when type is not declared in Transformer."""
    return x


Transformer = {
    "str": lambda x: x,
    "int": lambda x: int(x),
    "float": lambda x: float(x),
    "date": lambda x: date.fromisoformat(x),
}


reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

transformed = []
for row in reader:
    this_type, this_val = row[1], row[2]
    transformer_func = Transformer.get(this_type, default_f)
    val_transformed = transformer_func(this_val)
    transformed.append(row + [val_transformed])

    if transformer_func == default_f:
        print(f"warning: found undeclared type {this_type} with value {this_val}")


for row in transformed:
    print(row)
```

When I run that I get:

```
warning: found undeclared type foo with value ����
```

and,

```py
['Var1', 'int', '1', 1]
['Var2', 'date', '2022-08-01', datetime.date(2022, 8, 1)]
['Var3', 'int', '2', 2]
['Var4', 'str', 'Toaster oven', 'Toaster oven']
['Var5', 'float', '3.14159', 3.14159]
['Var6', 'foo', '����', '����']
```

I also found this library for dealing with OPC UA data, https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio, if it's easier to integrate their value transformers than make your own.